# Can an Oppo R9s be rooted?

Tags: rooting, oppo

I don't like the stock phone and messaging app of Oppo R9s (CPH 1607). Even when I install 3rd-party apps, the phone defaults to stock every time a call or message comes through. I am desperate to root it.

How can this be done?

Comment: They found a way that works on here:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-oppo-r9s-auto-root-tool-t3547546

Answer (score 2):

You can root your OPPO R9S using

1. iRoot

[image: iRoot]

2. Farmaroot
   [image: FarmaRoot]
3. KingoRoot
   [image]
   Check out [this](https://rootthat.blogspot.in/2017/01/how-to-root-oppo-r9s.html) blog for details. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help but none of these work.  i have tried them all.  root failed everytime.  even if the phone is not rootable, is there a way to stop the phone resetting to default applications?